# Efficient way to determine how many question marks in a row just before end of sentence

Tags: r, regex

I would like to detect the number of question marks in a row used just before the end of a sentence.

Consider the following minimal example:

```
> text1 <- "hello world?" # Answer should be 1
> text2 <- "hello world??" # Answer should be 2
> text3 <- "hello? world" # Answer should be 0
> text4 <- "?hello world" # Answer should be 0
```

A first attempt would be:

```
> stringr::str_count(text1, "\\?$")
[1] 1
> stringr::str_count(text2, "\\?$") # Wrong: answer here should be 2
[1] 1
> stringr::str_count(text3, "\\?$")
[1] 0
> stringr::str_count(text4, "\\?$")
[1] 0
```

From here I could think of some ways to perform the task, such as iteratively deleting the last "?" and re-running the search.

However, are there more efficient/natural ways to do in R with regex?

Comment: Did you try `\\?*$` ?

Comment: `str_count(text1, "\\?*$")` returns 2 here

Comment: Try it like this `nchar(regmatches(text1,regexpr("\\?*$",text1)))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`str_count` will return the number of matches. As the pattern matches questionmarks at the end of the string, the result is either 0 for no matches or 1 for a match.

If you want to count the amount of characters, you could for example get the match using `*` to match 0 or more times, and then count the number of characters.

```
nchar(regmatches(text1,regexpr("\\?*$",text1)))
```

Another option pointed out be @[BenBolker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/190277/ben-bolker) is to use

```
nchar(stringr::str_extract(text1, "\\?*$"))
```

Comment: or `stringr::str_extract()` if you want to stay in that world

Comment: @BenBolker Ow yes of course, like `nchar(stringr::str_extract(text1, "\\?*$"))`